# Hide port number in directadmin (:2222)

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, port, directadmin

Is there a way to hide the port in `directadmin`?

`server.example.com` instead `server.example.com:2222`

I do not know if this is possible at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kill all directadmin processes with this command

```
killall -9 directadmin
```

go to directadmin config directory

```
cd /usr/local/directadmin/conf/
vi directadmin.conf
```

find a line that contains this

```
port=2222
```

change it to something you want

save and exit with `:wq`

start directadmin

```
/etc/init.d/directadmin start
```

open your new port in firewall!